# Mixing for a gas of hard spheres

Tags: pr.probability, mp.mathematical-physics, ergodic-theory, statistical-physics, billiards

The gas of hard spheres is a model for a gas in a container, where each particle is a sphere of radius $\epsilon$. The spheres interact with each other and with the container with elastic collisions. The rigorous understanding of this model is far from complete. For example, *Boltzmann ergodic hypothesis* (i.e., whether this system is ergodic) is a major open problem in ergodic theory. Also, whether the Boltzmann equation can be derived as a limit of this model (aka the *Boltzmann-Grad limit*) is also open. My question is if the following (more modest) result is known:

Informal statement: Suppose the container is rectangular and initially the whole gas is in half of the container, restricted via a wall. At $t=0$, this wall is removed. Is it true that after sufficiently enough time, the left and right halves will be balanced?

For simplicity, I state it formally for 2d. If one is aware of a 3d result, please state it.

Formal statement:  The container is $[-a,a]\times [-b,b]$. The number of particles is $n$. We are interested in the regime where $n$ is large, the radius $\epsilon$ is small and $n\epsilon =\Theta(1)$. This is the Boltzmann-Grad scaling and is chosen this way to ensure that the average distance covered by a particle between two successive collisions is of order 1. The space of the particles' centers is the set $\mathcal{X}$ containing all tuples $(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ with $x_i\in [-a+\epsilon,a-\epsilon]\times [-b+\epsilon,b-\epsilon]$ and with pairwise distances satifying $\|x_i-x_j\|\ge \epsilon$ for $i\neq j$. Let $\mathcal{X_0}$ be the same as $\mathcal{X}$, but with $x_i\in [-a+\epsilon,-\epsilon]\times [-b+\epsilon,b-\epsilon]$. We fix a constant $K$, which will be the average kinetic energy. Now, we generate the initial positions and velocities as follows: we sample $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ uniformly at random from $\mathcal{X_0}$, and the tuple of velocities $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ uniformly at random from the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ centered at the origin and with radius $\sqrt{2Kn}$. The task is to prove that if $T$ is a moment in time (independent of the initialization), then with high probability (over the random initialization), at time $T$ the number $n_1$ of particles in the left half, and the number $n_2$ of particles in the right half satisfy $\frac{|n_1-n_2|}{n} \le f(T,N)$, where $f$ goes to zero as $T,N\to \infty$.